# Как из двух CSV файлов сделать третий, в котором будет список значений, общих для первых двух файлов

Tags: python, файлы, csv, join, обработка-данных

Дано два файла в формате csv с примерно следующим содержимым:

```
123;
456;
789;
```

Все значения числовые, размер одинаковый.
Необходимо сравнить строки первого файла со вторым и при совпадении значений записать строку в третий файл.

Comment: `comm -12 <(sort -u a.csv) <(sort -u b.csv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама написала сама ответила))

```
import requests
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('csvfile')
    parser.add_argument('csvfile2')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    filename1 = args.csvfile
    filename2 = args.csvfile2
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as response_file:
        with open(filename1) as msisdn1_file:
            for line in msisdn1_file.readlines():
                MSISDN1 = line.strip()
                b=False
                with open(filename2) as msisdn2_file:
                    for line in msisdn2_file.readlines():
                        MSISDN2 = line.strip()
                        if MSISDN1==MSISDN2:
                            b=True
                if b==True:
                    response_file.write(MSISDN1+'\n')      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Как ваш код коррелирует с вашим вопросом?

Comment: не то скопировала, извините

Comment: Ваш код очень неэффективный, потому что на каждую строку из первого файла вы заново читаете весь второй файл и сравниваете его построчно.

Comment: `import requests` не нужен, удалить бы его, кроме того, в питоне переменные в верхнем регистре считаются константами, а MSISDN1 и MSISDN2 константами не являются, это не критично, но лучше так не делать

Comment: @PyLam, подумал что будет полезно показать на примере доработанный код с учетом замечаний: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826655/201445

Answer (score 4):

Пример:

файл: `1.csv`:

```
a;b;c
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
```

файл: `2.csv`:

```
a;b;c
7;8;9
1;1;1
4;5;6
2;2;2
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=';')
d2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', sep=';')

d1.merge(d2).to_csv(r'res.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

результат:

```
a;b;c
4;5;6
7;8;9
```

Answer (score 3):

Привожу доработанный [ответ автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826269/201445), с учетом замечаний:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('csvfile')
parser.add_argument('csvfile2')

args = parser.parse_args()
filename1 = args.csvfile
filename2 = args.csvfile2

with open('result.csv', 'w') as response_file:
    with open(filename1) as f:
        msisdn1_lines = f.readlines()

    with open(filename2) as f:
        msisdn2_lines = f.readlines()

    # На каждую строчку msisdn1_lines
    for msisdn1 in msisdn1_lines:
        # Делаем перебор строк другого файла
        for msisdn2 in msisdn2_lines:
            if msisdn1 == msisdn2:
                response_file.write(msisdn1)
```

---

Алгоритм проверки можно упростить, если использовать метод [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) у множества (set), который вернет общие элементы:

```
with open('result.csv', 'w') as response_file:
    with open(filename1) as f:
        msisdn1_lines = set(f.readlines())

    with open(filename2) as f:
        msisdn2_lines = set(f.readlines())

    # Получаем список общих элементов
    common_lines = msisdn1_lines.intersection(msisdn2_lines)

    for line in common_lines:
        response_file.write(line)
```

**PS.** Метод intersection заменяется оператором `&`, поэтому можно просто:

```
common_lines = msisdn1_lines & msisdn2_lines
```

**PPS.** вместо цикла `for line in common_lines` можно одним махом записать в файл, если строки объединить в одну строку.

Было:

```
for line in common_lines:
    response_file.write(line)
```

станет:

```
response_file.write(''.join(common_lines))
```

Comment: от цикла `for line in common_lines:` можно тоже избавиться: `response_file.write('\n'.join(common_lines))`

Comment: @MaxU там даже разделитель не нужен, т.к. readlines возвратит строки с '\n', поэтому: `response_file.write(''.join(common_lines))`

Answer (score 1):

Для небольших файлов, чтобы найти общие для двух файлов числа, можно загрузить числа из каждого файл в set() и вывести их пересечение (не тестировано):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: common-numbers <file>..."""
import re
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def read_numbers(filename):
    return set(map(int, re.findall(br'\d+', Path(filename).read_bytes())))

print(*set.intersection(*map(read_numbers, sys.argv[1:])))
```

Пример запуска:

```
$ common-numbers a.csv b.csv
```